# Performance brute force hashing C++ Java

Tags: java, c++, performance, md5, brute-force

I implemented a brute-forcer for md5 in both C++ and Java and had questions about why their efficiency differed as it did.
The data and a plot of complexity (E^length of password) vs time is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPxD3.png
The passwords were simple "b"s repeated to fill the length

In C++ I used this implementation of md5: zedwood.com/article/cpp-md5-function
And in Java I used the second implementation on this site: http://www.asjava.com/core-java/java-md5-example/

In the recursive C++ implementation my code for looping was done in a separate class:

```
class bruteChar {
    string charset;
    char last_char;
    string str;
    string double_start;
    char reverse_charset[256];
  private:
    string next(string s)
    {
        size_t length = s.size()-1;
        if(length == 0)
        {
            if( s[0]==last_char)
                return double_start;
            return string(1, charset[reverse_charset[s[length]]+1]);
        }
        if(s[length] == last_char)
            return next(s.substr(0,length))+charset[0];
        else
            return str.substr(0,length)+string(1, charset[reverse_charset[s[length]]+1]);
    };

  public:
    void start (string chars)
    {
        charset = chars;
        str=charset[0];
        last_char=charset[charset.size()-1];
        double_start=charset[0];
        double_start+=charset[0];

        for(size_t i = 0; i < charset.size(); ++i)
            reverse_charset[charset[i]]=i;
        reverse_charset[charset[charset.size()]]=0;
    }

    string next()
    {
        str=next(str);
        return str;
    }
};
```

In Java I used a custom class

```
public class picochar {
    public static char[] charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray(); 
    int num;
    int mod;

    picochar(int init, int mod)
    {
        num = init%mod;
    }

    picochar(char init, int mod)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < mod; i++)
        {
            if(charset[i] == init)
                num = i;
        }  
    }

    public char get()
    {
        return charset[num];
    }

    public boolean equals(char  ch)
    {
        return (get() == ch);
    }

    public void increment()
    {
        num++;
    }
}
```

and the following method

```
public static String next(String s) {
    int length = s.length();
    picochar pc = new picochar(s.charAt(length - 1),mod);
    if(pc.equals(picochar.charset[mod-1]))
        return length > 1 ? next(s.substring(0, length - 1)) + 'a' : "aa";
    pc.increment();
    return s.substring(0, length - 1) + pc.get();
}
```

Why is Java much more efficient at calculating hashes than C++?
Did I simply use an efficient MD5 implementation for Java and a poor one for C++?
I assumed that C++ would be much faster than Java, as Java has to run everything through a JVM and C does it natively.

However, Java far outshone the C++ solution. If this was simply due to poor coding on my part of the C++ program, how would I fix that?

Edited to remove the dissimilar C++ program, now both solutions loop recursively.

I did some timing of how long it took to loop through without hashing, and here Java was twice as fast as C, which was explained by @Dunes. When recoded to not recursively use substr() and instead mutate the original string, C was around twice as fast as Java.

I did some tests of how long it take to hash "hello" 1<<25 times, and found something odd--Java seemed to "warm up" much faster, and though slower for at first would quickly catch up to the C implementation.
C++ would have a similar performance gain after having hashed for several seconds, but the gain was nowhere near as much as Java's.

So why does Java warm-up better?

Comment: I would try to make the code more similar.  The C++ and Java shouldn't look so different.  These differences are likely to explain the performance difference.

Comment: Well, as you said, you need to compare the same implementations. C++ will probably be faster in general, if done right. And a side note: this is not just because of JIT.

Comment: Another difference is you are using different MD5 libraries and this is where your program should be spending more of it's time.  I would try and see how these libraries compare for performance before looking at your code.

Comment: It's a myth that C/C++ is faster than Java.  If you write the same thing, the run time will be the same (probably faster on Java due to its internal optimizations).  People that claim that C/C++ is faster are either using optimized libraries or are writing bad Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using an inefficient md5 implementation.
Here's the times it took to compute 2<sup>27</sup> hashes versus the time it took openssl

```
openssl v1
17.4911

openssl v2
14.9546

custom
291.201
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the reason the c++ implementation is so slow is because you are passing strings around by value. That is each time you call a method with a string argument or return a string the program must make a brand new copy of the whole string.

Whereas, because Java has immutable strings it can get away with passing around different views of the same string. `String.substring` does not copy the backing char array. Instead the new string object just keeps track of the start index and length in relation to the backing char array. When substring is used unwisely it can lead to memory leaks - a one char view will keep an original million char backing array alive, so long as it exists.

Comment: Ah! I tried to make the two loops as similar as possible, but didn't know how they operated under the hood.